# Initialize a Python Poetry project without human interaction

Tags: python, devops, python-poetry

I'd love to initialize a poetry-generated project without going through the interactive shell for versions and dependencies etc.

However, a few attempts of fiddling around with the command line options all failed.

Such as

```sh
poetry init --name my_proj --description  "my proj" --author john.doe --python 3.9 --dependency "pytest:^6.2.0" --dev-dependency coverage -l MIT
```

gives me the interactive shell to confirm all the info I provided.

### Expectation

I expect that by giving all the dependencies, the command should generate a `pyproject.toml` automatically without me entering anything.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add `-n` or `--no-interaction` to your command and you will get what you are asking for.

Comment: ah!!! my bad. Totally missed this at the bottom of the help message! Thanks a lot!

Comment: But it still goes against the instinct that "since we decide to give options in one line, we most probably don't want interruptions from now on until the command ends", wouldn't you agree?